# How to route your actionName correctly without error/application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I am struggling to get my routing page well its given me an error, please help. The logic is below, i want to route to the course-registration page. Currently its giving me an error/Application, what could i be missing based on a given scenario?

```
 // Route to Courses.

            routes.MapRoute(
                name:"Courses",
                url:"courses-registration/",
                defaults: new {controller="Home", action="Courses-Registration", url=UrlParameter.Optional}

            );

// HomeController
 public ActionResult Courses()
        {
            return View();
        }

// View
<div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <a class="btn btn-large btn-success" id="fire" href="@Url.Action("Courses-Registration","Home")">Create Courses</a>
                        <script type="text/javascript">    
                            $('#fire').on('click', function (e) {



                            });
                            </script>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Your action needs to be the name of the actionresult in your controller. Try changing action="Courses-Registration" to action="Courses" in your route

Comment: @Carl i still not getting it right, url:localhost:portnumber:/Home/courses-registration. Error/Application. What am i missing?

Comment: the url you have set for your courses page is localhost:port/courses-registration - try browsing to that